# Designing an MVC (web) application from scratch – What Are the basic (necessary and optional) components I should be aware of?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns

I’m about to write quite a big web site that will basically be a forum, divided to (many) different subjects and allow users’ score.

I’ll be using MVC, so I (“naively”) asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747383/best-practices-to-partition-model-code-to-logical-parts-in-mvc-which-is-the-best1.) question about how to partition the Model portion  of MVC, which is likely to be very large.
Two things I realized from the answers I got:

1. I really don’t know much about designing software.
2. There are many ways to implement MVC

So I have now two questions:

1. (That’s a bit theoretical-) Would
   you say designing a software is
   completely deterministic i.e.- For a
   specific set of requirements there
   is one best design? If not- why?
2. What are the common components
       (necessary and optional) of MVC that
       I should consider in writing my site
       (resources for beginners would be
       great)?

Comment: Just curious:  what platforms are you considering?  Rails, ASP.NET MVC, or something else?  I'm not sure if when you say MVC you mean specifically "ASP.NET MVC", or the design pattern.

Comment: I do use ASP.NET MVC, but my question isn't specifically about it..

Comment: Although Java/JSP/Servlet targeted, you may get some useful insights out of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/3542297#3542297).

Comment: @BalusC: can you make that a "formal" answer so that I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although Java/JSP/Servlet targeted, you may get some useful insights out of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/3542297#3542297). It describes the common patterns to be used in MVC and the approach how to fit them all together. Here's a summary:

- [Front Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) ([Mediator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern)) - the controller
- [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) - the business actions
- [Abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) - to let controller obtain the desired business action.
- [Facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) - to abstract the raw HTTP details away.
- [State pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) - to introduce a lifecycle which abstracts gathering of request parameters, validation, conversion, updating model values, etc away.
- [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) - to create an advanced component tree for the view.

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.Net MVC, a good entry level, free tutorial is the 'MVC 2 Music Store' by Jon Galloway.  You can find it [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2010/05/12/introducing-the-mvc-music-store-mvc-2-sample-application-and-tutorial.aspx).  Note that the current version of ASP.Net MVC is MVC 2.

A more thorough tutorial is the Nerd Dinner tutorial.  However the creators are still in the process of updating it to MVC 2.   You can check for updates and downloads [here](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/).

I would recommend using resources for MVC 2 as there are some significant improvements over the first version.  Also MVC 3 is on the horizon and you want to hit the ground running.

I would also recommend keeping an eye on MVC 3 improvements if you're serious about getting up to speed in this space.  A good blog to subscribe to is Phil Haack's [Haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/27/aspnetmvc3-preview1-released.aspx). Phil is the project manager for MVC at Microsoft.

In terms of textbooks, the gold standard is Steven Sanderson's 'Pro ASP.Net MVC 2 Framework'.  The first review on Amazon is from Scott Guthrie, a Microsoft VP, who raves about the book.  He also has a competing book of his own.  You can get the ebook from Apress [here](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430228865).  Do a google search for Apress promo codes and you may save a few dollars.

Good luck.

Comment: Actually I read Pro ASP.Net MVC 2 Framework right now.. That's what got me wondering about implementing MVC (in general) in the first place. But thanks for all the resources..

Answer (score 1):

Software is definitely not deterministic. Theories in programming are constantly developing and improving, which is what makes the field such a fast-paced and exciting place to work. Also, what may seem like the best approach to a software problem right now could be obsolete in a matter of months by a newer, improved technology.