# Application design patterns reference

Tags: design-patterns

i know there a lot of topics discuss design patterns, and also every one would say each pattern has it pros & cons, and every one should choose the one that most suits his needs,

but here i want from every expert to share his experience with design patterns, as for me i started a new application, and when starting in its architecture design, i really got confused,

it's a very important phase, some need their app to be scalable, maintainable, expandable,

i want to find a path to move through, so please if you can share ideas, experience, that would be great,

Regards,

Comment: At least give us some details about your app.. Is it a web app? What are it's main features?

Comment: I voted to close the question. The reason is that currently your question (if we turn it into a positive form) looks pretty much like a preface for a book about design patterns written by a group of proven experts. Try to describe you concrete problems and we'll try to help you.

Comment: Hi Oren A, my app is a web app, and i know i didn't clarify it, sorry if the question isn't written well, but i didn't want to mention a specific app type, so we can get most benefits from experts, please tell me if you think it's not a correct answer, Regards

Answer (score 0):

Although mainly about MVC, [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747383/best-practices-to-partition-model-code-to-logical-parts-in-mvc-which-is-the-best) may help.

Comment: could we also use it with SaaS apps ?, and what if i want to build an app that will have different View implementation (Clients),

Comment: MVC is a design pattern.. It's not limited to a certain technology or implementation. Don't know enough in order to answer about SaaS tough..